# printing a gridsearch in 3D for hyperparameter visualization

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, mplot3d

Trying to visualize hyperparamt and the result of them, I CAN NOT get to plot them in a 3d plot

I try to build a function as:

```
PlotGridSearch(grid,xparam,yparam,zlabels):
```

to be called as

```
gs= GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier()
                 ,HyperParams
                 , scoring='accuracy'
                 , cv=50).fit(train_data,train_labels)

 PlotGridSearch(gs
                ,'param_max_depth'
                ,'param_max_leaf_nodes'
                ,'mean_test_score')
```

But I can get to convert the mean_test_score columns to the necesary matrix (2 dimensional arrray) with the correct labels stracted from param_max_depth y param_max_leaf_nodes

any tips ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice official documentation about [3D surface matplotlib plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html).

```
# This import registers the 3D projection, but is otherwise unused.
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

# Customize the z axis.
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

If you are running python in Jupyter Notebook, you can use `%matplotlib notebook` to make it interactive.

And in your case, if you want to get the proper X,Y and Z, you could get the values from `gs.cv_results_`, which is:

```
m = len(param_grid['max_depth'])
n = len(param_grid['max_leaf_nodes'])
X = np.reshape(gs.cv_results_['param_max_depth'].data,[n,m]) # do mind the order of reshape, it might diff
Y = np.reshape(gs.cv_results_['param_max_leaf_nodes'].data,[n,m])
Z = np.reshape(gs.cv_results_['mean_test_score'],[n,m])
```

Comment: yes, that I know, the problem I have is to make the data as the X, Y, Z, R, Z example you have here

Comment: gs= GridSearchCV just return a table with all columns , no grouping by axes

Comment: @figarom. You can use `numpy.reshpe` to get the correct value, but do remember to check the order of the parameters. I add another example to show how to do it.